# Circular Ping Pong Game

Tags: python, pygame, geometry

I'm trying to develop a simple circular pong game in pygame.
The game looks something like this.

[image: Ping pong game]

At the moment I struggle with the direction of the ball after it hits the
palette (that is theoretically just an arc).

So far I've done this but things don't seem that natural.

```
def getNewTraiectory(staAng, stpAng, ball, angle):    
    if(ball.speedX > 2.2 or ball.speedY > 2.2):
        ball.speedX /= 2
        ball.speedY /= 2
        
    if (abs(angle-staAng) < abs(stpAng - angle )):
        ball.speedX -=(stpAng - angle)/40
        ball.speedY +=(stpAng - angle)/40

    elif (abs(angle-staAng) > abs(stpAng - angle )):
        ball.speedX += (angle - staAng)/40
        ball.speedY -= (angle - staAng)/40

    speed = random.uniform(0.7,1.96)
    ball.speedX *= (-1)*(speed)
    ball.speedY *= (-1)*(speed)
```

Where `staAng` is the starting angle of the pallete, `stpAngle` is the stopping angle of the pallete, `ball` is an object of the class `Ball` (that has a speed on axis X, a speed on axis Y and a position on both axes).

Theoretically, I just check the place where the ball hits on the sprite (close to the starting angle or closer to the stopping angle and based on that I try to give a somewhat opposite direction).

Can you help me to find a better method to give the direction of the ball bouncing the palletes?

Comment: This seems to be a math question, not a programming question?

Comment: It is not clear - how "arc bat" influences on ball moving. Does ball reflect as from standing arc wall? Does moving bat make impact into tangential/normal component of the ball speed?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you mean by that. The arcs are moving based on the user input. If the ball reaches the distance to the tangent of the circle, it checks for collision and if there is collision, the ball must change direction ( it must bounce ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal vector of a circle is the vector from the point on the circle to the center of the circle. Use [`pygame.math.Vector2.reflect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.reflect) to reflect the ball from the circle.
In the following `direction`, `center_point`, `hit_point` and `new_dircection` are [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) objects. `center_point` is the center of the circle, `hit_point` is the point where the ball collides with the circle and `direction` is the direction of movement of the ball:

```py
new_dircection = direction.reflect(hit_point - center_point)
```

Comment: I've implemented that but doing that the ball only bounces back and forward on the same direction. I need to something that changes direction based on the spot hit on the arc.

Comment: @AndreiBalanescu So you did it wrong. `direction.reflect` calculates a reflected direction (like a pool ball).

Comment: I've transformed each ball speed, board position and ball position into vector2s. then i pretty much used new_direction = ballSpeedVector.reflect(ballVector-boardVector) .

Comment: Are you sure that the reflected values should be based on ball - board vectors ? My guess was that it should be related with arcs

Comment: @AndreiBalanescu Yes I am sure. And it is related to the arc, because `hit_point - center_point` depends on the arc. `center_point` is the center of the circular area.